Crear un vinculo en JS con una referencia https
soy nueva usando Javascript. Debo crear un vinculo con una referencia https pero lo he intentado según el ejemplo y no me funciona.
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var contenido = document.createTextNode("Wikipedia");
    a.setAttribute("href","https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada");
    a.appendChild(contenido);
    p.appendChild(a);



user393237, saber preguntar también es algo bueno. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para que no cierren tus preguntas futuras...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual es la parte que no funciona?

En la parte de interfaces podes encontrar todas las clases de los elementos (HTML...Element) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces

Snippet con JS puro


var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Mi Link");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "Mi Link con JS";
a.href = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/";
document.body.appendChild(a);



Snippet desde HTML (que al final es lo mismo)


<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      var linkText = document.createTextNode("Mi Link");
      a.appendChild(linkText);
      a.title = "Mi Link con JS";
      a.href = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/";
      document.body.appendChild(a);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




Muchas gracias quedo solucionado!!

Me alegra que te haya servido. Por favor, marca la respuesta como aceptada para un mejor orden en el sitio.
